# "Broken platform 'JDK_17'" when opening a java project on netbeans 16.1 on Arch Linux

Tags: netbeans, archlinux

I have installed jdk 17 through pacman's default package: "openjdk 17.0.6 2023-01-17
"

And I also have netbeans 16-1 also using pacman (I know there is the 17 version available but I want it the fast setup and from what I searched, it supports JDK 17)

When I open, it displays that message on the title. I edited the /etc/netbeans.conf file so the netbeans_jdkhome variable is: "netbeans_jdkhome="/usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk/" but the problem still persists.

What else can I do? Thanks in advance